# What is the difference between Qiskit Terra, Aer, Ignis and Aqua?

Tags: qiskit, programming

I am going through the Qiskit tutorials and they have an article on each of the above 4. however, As a beginner, I am not very clear. Could anyone share some insights on these?

Comment: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stable/0.24/the_elements.html

Answer (score 5):

Back in Qiskit 0.24 (around March 2021) Qiskit was organized in Elements, as [KAJ226 points out](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/22047/what-is-the-difference-between-ibm-terra-aer-ignis-and-aqua#comment30203_22047). However, after 0.25, Aqua was broken up in domain specific packages and the [Aqua deprecation process started](https://qiskit.org/documentation/aqua_migration.html). At the end of 2021, Ignis was also deprecated to be replaced by `qiskit-experiments`. The current Qiskit landscape looks roughly like this:

[image: Qiskit landscape]

- **Qiskit Terra** ([repo](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/) [package](https://pypi.org/project/qiskit-terra/)), the core module that handles quantum circuit construction, circuit analysis and transformation, and general use algorithms, such as VQE.
- **Qiskit Aer** [repo](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aer) [package](https://pypi.org/project/qiskit-aer/)), for quantum simulators.
- **Qiskit Application packages**, these are 4 modules, Machine Learning ([repo](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-machine-learning) [package](https://pypi.org/project/qiskit-machine-learning/)), Nature ([repo](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-nature) [package](https://pypi.org/project/qiskit-nature/)), Finance ([repo](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-finance) [package](https://pypi.org/project/qiskit-finance/)), and Optimization ([repo](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-optimization) [package](https://pypi.org/project/qiskit-optimization/)), they target specific domains and plug into the tools used by experts.
- **Qiskit Dynamics** ([repo](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-dynamics) [package](https://pypi.org/project/qiskit-dynamics)) provides access to different numerical methods for solving differential equations
- **Qiskit IBM** Quantum Provider (current [repo](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibmq-provider/) [package](https://pypi.org/project/qiskit-ibmq-provider/), soon to be moved to [repo](https://github.com/Qiskit-Partners/qiskit-ibm)), the module that enables Qiskit to access IBM quantum devices in the cloud.
- **Qiskit Experiments** ([repo](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-experiments) [package](https://pypi.org/project/qiskit-experiments)), replacing Ignis ([repo](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ignis) [package](https://pypi.org/project/qiskit-ignis)), the module that contains all the required tools to implement error mitigation techniques.
- **Qiskit Metal** ([repo](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-metal/) [package](https://pypi.org/project/qiskit-metal/)) is a framework for engineering and designing superconducting quantum devices.

This landscape is constantly changing and hard to follow. The best place to learn about past and future changes is this [wiki page](https://github.com/qiskit-community/feedback/wiki/Release-Planning) maintained by the Qiskit community team.

Comment: Is is appropriate to call this Qiskit architecture (as of today)?

Comment: https://medium.com/qiskit/what-is-qiskit-your-guide-to-navigating-the-qiskit-cosmos-in-2022-7cc415426f31 calls it "Qiskit cosmos". potayto, potahto :)